# Detect and shorten ALL urls in string

Tags: java, regex, string, url

Suppose I have a String message:

"you should upload file.zip to http://google.com/extremelylonglink.zip, not https://stackoverflow.com/extremelylonglink.zip. try again."

I want a function to return to String newmessage:

"you should upload file.zip to [shorted version of first link], not [shortened version of second link]. try again."

I already have the code for the URL shortener, and here is my URL detection code that replaces the first URL in a message:

```
        if(message.contains("http://") || message.contains("https://")) {
            String regex = "(?i)\\b((?:https?://|www\\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}/)(?:[^\\s()<>]+|\\(([^\\s()<>]+|(\\([^\\s()<>]+\\)))*\\))+(?:\\(([^\\s()<>]+|(\\([^\\s()<>]+\\)))*\\)|[^\\s`!()\\[\\]{};:'\".,<>?«»“”‘’]))";
            Matcher m = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(message);
            if (m.find()) {
                String url = m.group();
                    String shorted = null;      
                        try {       
                             shorted = Shortener.GetShortedISGD(url);                                                                           
                        } catch (IOException e1) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        }
                    }
                    String intercepted = message.replace(url, shorted);
                    e.setMessage(intercepted);
        }
```

How would I go about replacing ALL of them?
(I'm using the Bukkit API for a lot of this, so a lot of the functions aren't in Java).

I'm thinking of splitting up message into an array of words, and then evaluating if each word would be a URL, except that would be kinda not  optimized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `appendReplacement` and `appendTail`. See [example](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/matcher.html) in the Java tutorial and [another example](http://www.coderanch.com/t/375438/java/java/appendReplacement-appendTail) closer to what you are trying to do.

Comment: Try it and let me know! But, here is [another example](http://www.coderanch.com/t/375438/java/java/appendReplacement-appendTail) closer to what you are trying to do using `appendReplacement` and `appendTail`.

Comment: How would I do that for a possibly infinite number of props?

Comment: In that example, `props` is just a dictionary of replacements. You don't need or want that here as your `GetShortedISGD` provides the replacement value. You will just append `Shortener.GetShortedISGD(m.group(1))` each time through the `while` loop.